# Sitecore 7.2 :Could not find property 'showVersionForAllAssemblies' on object of type: Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I get below issue when installing Sitecore 7.2 rev. 140526

"Could not find property 'showVersionForAllAssemblies' on object of type: Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion".

Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade from an older version to 7.2 rev140526? The exception indicates your are using an old version of Sitecore.Kernel.dll

Comment: No Ruud.I was installing sitecore 7.2 with Visual Studio Professional 2012

No Ruud. I followed the below step and got this issue 
1. Instaled Sitecore 7.2 rev. 140526 
2. To get MVC 5 template in 2012 I installed ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012 
   Referred the below link for this:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532 
3. Created Sitecore MVC Project.
4. Then got a error saying unable to load Sitecore.Analytics
5. Installed Analytics
6. Now I get this issue.

Comment: Can you try to install and run Sitecore first, before creating a VS2012 solution? Just to see if it runs after a plain installation.

Comment: Can you check what is the version of `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` in the bin directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a reference to the old version of Sitecore.Kernel.dll in your project somewhere still. I had a similar issue and was able to resolve by simply checking all the references to Sitecore.Kernel.dll and making sure they were using 7.2. That 'showVersionForAllAssemblies' is added in one of the more recent versions.

Comment: Hi goose I thought your solution is gonna fix my issue right on but I updated the references to point to Sitecore.Kernel from the actual version I am using (which is 7.1) but i still get the same error above. Any idea?

Comment: From what I remember of this message, that setting it's talking about in the error is something that was only added in the later versions of Sitecore so if you're seeing that message, it probably means there is still a sneaky dll somewhere. Perhaps check your /bin directory and any folders yo use to source your sitecore dlls just to be sure?

Comment: Hi Goose, Thanks for getting back to me. Pretty close actually yes it was a reference in the .csproj file pf my Data project. that fixed my issue. thanks